# In Blender, How export animation with single key?

Tags: animation, .fbx

I want to use an animation in Unity called "smile_anim.fbx". In this animation, the bones do not move. This animation is designed to fix the bones in a smiling pose. However, I am unable to export such an animation with Blender.

In Blender, I have keyed multiple frames with the same value for Location, Rotation or Scale. When I output this animation to FBX, the keys are automatically deleted.

In a simpler example, if I key Location, Rotation and Scale on frame 1 and try to output that animation, the keys are deleted when I output to FBX.

If I key on frame 2 with different values, I can output it as a keyed animation, but if I key the same values, the keys are deleted.

I think this is a serious bug, but how can I work around it?

Note that in the FBX output settings, [Bake Animation]>[Force Start/End Keying] is turned off. The reason is that all I want to do is output only the keys I set as I set them.

I have tried with [Bake Animation]>[Force Start/End Keying] on, but it is not the desired behavior. This is because, in addition to the eye and mouth bones, extra bones such as spines and arms are also keyed. More to the point, the scale is not output.